# Spring and Dropwizard: Running a scheduled task after app has fully started up

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

This is a very general question about best practice, so I apologize in advance if it shouldn't go here.

I'm trying to set up a task schedule to check to see what rules in a database are active, using spring task scheduler.  These rules will be added to a hashmap for reference.  As of right now, we have an `init()` method that runs in Dropwizard's run method in the main application class.  I've set up a `refresh` method to check every 5 seconds after it runs, using the Spring task scheduler in the Spring XML configuration file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.db"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="ruleDAO" method="refreshRules" initial-delay="10000" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="scheduler"/>
```

This does technically work.  However, I don't like the idea of hardcoding that 10 second initial delay in the XML file;  I would like to set this up to run 10 seconds after `init()` finishes, to ensure that there is no crossover between the two methods.  Is there anyway to do this in the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

If your `init()`  method is a `PostConstruct`, the scheduler will wait until after `init()` completes at the moment due to the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.